# Different program outputs when different capacity arguments are passed to List constructor, C#

Tags: c#

I'm implementing a slightly fancier version of counting sort in C#. The "slightly fancier" part is that I replace some elements in the sorted output with "-" rather than the original value. Here is a sample input/ output pair (the range of possible integer values are between 0 and 99):

IN

```
20
0 ab
6 cd
0 ef
6 gh
4 ij
0 ab
6 cd
0 ef
6 gh
0 ij
4 that
3 be
0 to
1 be
5 question
1 or
2 not
4 is
2 to
4 the
```

OUT

```
- - - - - to be or not to be - that is the question - - - -
```

And here is my implementation:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
class Solution 
{

    static void Main(String[] args) 
    {
        int n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        List<List<string>> rsltLists = new List<List<string>>(100);
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
        {
            rsltLists.Add(new List<String>()); // PROBLEM IS HERE
        }

        for(int a0 = 0; a0 < n; a0++)
        {
            string[] tokens_x = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');
            int x = Convert.ToInt32(tokens_x[0]);
            string s = tokens_x[1];
            if(a0 < n/2)
            {
                // Replace string with '-'
                rsltLists[x].Add("-");
            } 
            else 
            {               
                rsltLists[x].Add(s);
            }
        }

        foreach(List<string> rsltList in rsltLists)
        {
            foreach(string rslt in rsltList)
            {
                Console.Write(rslt + " ");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm submitting my code as the solution to [a problem on Hackerrank](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/countingsort4/problem). The problem is that for the 5th test case, my solution times out (the test case contains an enormous number of lines so I'm not including it here). To speed my solution up, I replaced the `//PROBLEM IS HERE` line with `rsltLists.Add(new List<String>(100))`. This causes the 5th test case to fail rather than time out (test cases 1-4 still passed). When I replaced the problem line with `rsltLists.Add(new List<String>(10000))` the 5th test case *and* several other test cases failed (though not all of the test cases failed). Why would changing the amount of space I reserve for each `List<String>` cause this inconsistent behavior? I would expected the fifth test case to fail (maybe), but I wouldn't have expected test cases that were passing previously to start failing.

Comment: Fails how? With what error?

Comment: What test cases are you referring to?

Comment: Well did you compare the output with the test data?

Comment: I'm confused. You allocate rsltLists to reserve 100 slots and then you write `n` items into it.  **Why are you not reserving `n` slots if you know ahead of time that's how many you need?**

Comment: You say that the size is "enormous".  For some people anything more than 1000 is enormous and for some people anything more than a quadrillion is enormous. Don't say it's "enormous". **Say how big it is**. It matters.

Comment: @EricLippert The test case that fails contains n=1,000,000 lines. The answers so far are faster solutions, and I know I could improve my solution with them, but what I'm really curious about is why I'm getting different test failures when I pass different integers to the `List<String>` constructor

Comment: Maybe the hacker rank server is running out of memory if I ask for that too much space when creating the `List`s

Comment: My guess would be yes, that the service which compiles submissions is running in an environment which detects when unusually large amounts of memory are being allocated.  If it's a 64 bit machine then a million lists of 100 strings takes up almost a gigabyte just for the underlying arrays. Now, if that's the case then I would expect it to fail with an out of memory error, not a timeout.

Comment: It's also possible that attempting to find a million 1KB chunks of memory is simply taking a while for the managed heap to find and allocate. If that gig of pages doesn't fit into RAM then *every single time you touch one you are triggering a hit to the page file*, and that is not fast.

Comment: hacker rank isn't great about telling you why your test case failed. Maybe what's happening is that when `()` is used the timeout happens before the out of memory error happens. And when `(100)` or `(10000)` is used the out of memory error occurs, but is surfaced to the user as a failed test case

Comment: But what I don't understand is why you are allocating any memory at all.  What have you got? A sequence of int, string pairs.  So start by representing that. Make a pair class and then:    `static IEnumerable<Pair<int, string>> Pairs() {
        int n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        for(int a = 0; a < n; a++){
            string[] t = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');
            yield return new Pair<int, string>() { k=Convert.ToInt32(t[0]), v=a >= n / 2 ? t[1] : "-" };
        }
    }`

Comment: And then the solution is just a single expression: `string.Join(" ", Pairs().OrderBy(p=>p.k).Select(p=>p.v))`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167441/discussion-between-adam-and-eric-lippert).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you creating `n rsltLists`?  That is not the requirement.  There are 100 possible values and array is better for that.  You should NOT be using n here. x is 100.

```
for(int i=0; i<n; i++)  // no, problem is here
{
    rsltLists.Add(new List<String>()); // PROBLEM IS HERE
}
```

This should be pretty fast

```
public static string HackerSort()
{
    List<string> input = new List<string>() {"20"
                                            , "0 ab"
                                            , "6 cd"
                                            , "0 ef"
                                            , "6 gh"
                                            , "4 ij"
                                            , "0 ab"
                                            , "6 cd"
                                            , "0 ef"
                                            , "6 gh"
                                            , "0 ij"
                                            , "4 that"
                                            , "3 be"
                                            , "0 to"
                                            , "1 be"
                                            , "5 question"
                                            , "1 or"
                                            , "2 not"
                                            , "4 is"
                                            , "2 to"
                                            , "4 the" };
    List<string>[] wl = new List<string>[100];
    int n = int.Parse(input[0]);
    int half = n/2;
    char split = ' ';
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        string s = input[i + 1];
        string[] ss = s.Split(split);
        //Debug.WriteLine(ss[0]);
        int row = int.Parse(ss[0]);
        if(wl[row] == null)
        {
            wl[row] = new List<string>((n / 100) + 1);
        }
        wl[row].Add(i  < half ? "-" : ss[1]);            
    }
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach(List<string> ls in wl.Where(x => x != null))
    {
        sb.Append(string.Join(" ", ls) + ' ');
    }
    Debug.WriteLine(sb.ToString().TrimEnd());
    return sb.ToString().TrimEnd();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The "inner" List will always have exactly two elements, one of which you want to treat as a number rather than a string. Better to use a small class or even a tuple here, rather than nested lists.

I'm at work with only VS2015 with no tuple support, so this code is unchecked and likely has a mistake or two:

```
static void Main(String[] args) 
{
    int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    var data = new List<(int, string)>(n);

    for(int a0 = 0; a0 < n; a0++)
    {
        var tokens = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');
        int x = int.Parse(tokens[0]);
        if(a0 < n/2) tokens[1] = "-";

       data.Add( (val: x, str: tokens[1]) )
    }

    foreach(var item in data.OrderBy(i => i.val))
    {
        Console.Write(item.str + " ");
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem on hackerrank doesn't seem to support the C# 6 tuples but the logic looks mostly sound. However, I'm not sure it'd pass the efficiency requirements as I believe LINQ's `OrderBy` will not be as efficient as the "Counting Sort" which is the purpose of the problem. Additionally, I don't believe it's guaranteed to be a "stable" sort.

Comment: OrderBy() does guarantee a stable sort

Answer (score 0):

Couple thoughts on this:

- You're creating a list for each option... but many aren't used. How about only instantiating the lists that you'll actually use?
- Compounded with the one above, you're creating 100 lists, each with a capacity of 100... that's a lot of memory to set aside that you won't be using

One solution:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
class Solution 
{
    static void Main(String[] args) 
    {
        int n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        int threshold = n / 2;
        List<string>[] stringMap = new List<string>[100];
        for(int a0 = 0; a0 < n; a0++){
            string[] tokens_x = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');
            int x = Convert.ToInt32(tokens_x[0]);
            if(stringMap[x] == null)
            {
                stringMap[x] = new List<string>();
            }
            stringMap[x].Add((a0 >= threshold ? tokens_x[1] : "-"));
        }

        List<string> output = new List<string>();
        for(int i = 0; i < stringMap.Length; i++)
        {
            if(stringMap[i] == null)
            {
                continue;
            }

            output.AddRange(stringMap[i]);
        }

        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", output));
    }
}
```

Comment: He uses all the items. He needs the "-" for the extra entries.

Comment: "-" is handled as a ternary on line 20. And by "extra entries" I mean the number values (x in the code) - the constraints allow for `0 <= x < 100` but that doesn't mean he's going to use all 100 possibilities but he's allocating them anyway. This sample passes all test cases on the problem at hackerrank so I know it works. That  doesn't mean I'm not open to improvement on it but it resolves the test cases he's failing and it should be pretty efficient.

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve the memory-hogging / long processing times would be to store the input in a `SortedDictionary<int, List<string>>` instead. The `Key` would be the integer portion of the input, and the `Value` would be a `List<string>` containing the other part of the input (one item per input that matches the key).

Then, when we have the dictionary populated, we can just output each `List<string>` of data in order (the `SortedDictionary` will already be sorted by `Key`).

In this way, we're only creating as many lists as we actually need, and each list is only as long as it needs to be (both of which I believe were causes for the errors in your original code, but I don't know where to find the actual test case code to verify).

```
private static void Main()
{
    var length = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    var halfway = length / 2;
    var items = new SortedDictionary<int, List<string>>();

    for (int inputLine = 0; inputLine < length; inputLine++)
    {
        var input = Console.ReadLine().Split();
        var sortIndex = Convert.ToInt32(input[0]);
        var value = inputLine < halfway ? "-" : input[1];

        if (items.ContainsKey(sortIndex)
        {
            items[sortIndex].Add(value);
        }
        else
        {
            items.Add(sortIndex, new List<string> {value});
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", items.SelectMany(i => i.Value)));

    // Not submitted to website, but for local testing:
    Console.Write("\n\nPress any key to exit...");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

**Output**

[image]